# How to update a foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create two tables, customer and customer_order.

And set the column custmoer_email (foreign_key and unique)
I tried to make the following code to update the column:

```
UPDATE customer 
SET customer_email = 'user2@email.com'
WHERE customer_email = 'user@email.com';
```

So that gave me an error due to a foreign key, how do you do to update the information of the customer_email?

Comment: To what table is `customer_email` referencing? When updating a `foreign key`, the new value must exist in the referenced table.

Comment: An email address is not a great candidate for a foreign key. Even though email addresses don't change often if they do you end up with the problem you are experiencing. I would create a new record with the correct email and copy of other fields after that I would delete the old rows

Comment: Example: insert customer (fname, lname, email) select fname, lname, 'new@email.com' from customer where email = 'old@email.com' once this is done a similar insert can be performed on customer_order

Comment: You're quite right, but the problem is wanted to make a link between the two tables and the email is the only medium that can do this.

Comment: I am assuming you are using the email address as the primary key. What you could do is add a customer_ID as a guild or numeric identity column making this the primary key and then put a unique index on the email address. Now you are free to use the customer_id in the foreign key table and you still ensure that the rows in customer have unique email addresses.

Comment: No, my primary key is customer_id

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are using the email as a foreign key reference in orders.  When you change the email, you end up with a "dangling" reference to `'user@email.com'`.

What you want is a cascading foreign key reference.  Something like this:

```
alter table orders add constraint fk_orders_customer_email
    foreign key (customer_email) references customers(customer_email)
        on update cascade;
```

(Do this after dropping the existing constraint.)

As mentioned in the comments, though, it is better to have a customer id and to use that.  Then you can change the email with no such issues.